# OpenSSL - ContentInfo having Content set in addition to ContentType without specifying this

Tags: c++, openssl, digital-signature, pades

I'm trying to create a PAdES digital signature based on PDFNet API. The problem is that the signature is not recognized by [DSS Verification](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation) due to Content field from ContentInfo which should not exist according to [PAdES standard](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf). This is also marked as optional in [RFC5652](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652), chapter 3.

This is the field that is causing the problem:

[image: Content NULL]

This is my code:

```
if (this->digest.size() == 0) {
        this->digest.resize(this->digest_size);
        EVP_DigestFinal(this->hash_context, &(this->digest[0]), NULL);
    }

    PKCS7* p7 = PKCS7_new();
    PKCS7_set_type(p7, NID_pkcs7_signed);


    PKCS7_add_certificate(p7, this->x509_cert);

    for (int c = 0; c < sk_X509_num(this->x509_chain); c++) {
        X509* cert = sk_X509_value(this->x509_chain, c);
        PKCS7_add_certificate(p7, cert);
    }

    PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO* p7Si = PKCS7_add_signature(p7, x509_cert, priv_key, EVP_get_digestbyname(hash_type.c_str()));

    PKCS7_add1_attrib_digest(p7Si, &(this->digest[0]), this->digest_size);
    PKCS7_add_attrib_content_type(p7Si, OBJ_nid2obj(NID_pkcs7_data));


    ESS_SIGNING_CERT_V2* signing_cert = OSSL_ESS_signing_cert_v2_new_init(EVP_get_digestbyname(this->hash_type.c_str()), this->x509_cert, NULL, -1);

    int len_sign_cert = i2d_ESS_SIGNING_CERT_V2(signing_cert, NULL);
    unsigned char* encoded_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(len_sign_cert * sizeof(unsigned char));
    unsigned char* p = encoded_data;
    i2d_ESS_SIGNING_CERT_V2(signing_cert, &p);
    ASN1_STRING* seq = ASN1_STRING_new();
    ASN1_STRING_set(seq, encoded_data, len_sign_cert);
    PKCS7_add_signed_attribute(p7Si, NID_id_smime_aa_signingCertificateV2, V_ASN1_SEQUENCE, seq);

    
    PKCS7_content_new(p7, NID_pkcs7_data);
    PKCS7_set_detached(p7, 1);
    

    PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO_sign(p7Si);
```

I tried to use CMS instead of PKCS7 so I can workaround the problem, but there is also a problem there because the signingTime field is set automatically at the call of CMS_SignerInfo_sign (and this field shall not be prezent in a PAdES digital signature).